# Position fixed - retorna para onde estava com o scroll do mouse

Tags: jquery

Tenho esse script em Jquery que quando o scroll do mouse passa por ela determinada div, deixa fixa uma div com position:fixed.

Ali emabaixo tem PARAR AQUI, é ali que eu quero que volte pro lugar, como posso fazer

```js
function sticky_relocate() {
    var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
    var div_top = $('#sticky-anchor').offset().top;
    if (window_top > div_top) {
        $('#sticky').addClass('stick');
        $('#sticky-anchor').height($('#sticky').outerHeight());
    } else {
        $('#sticky').removeClass('stick');
        $('#sticky-anchor').height(0);
    }
}

$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(sticky_relocate);
    sticky_relocate();
});
```

```css
#sticky {
    padding: 0.5ex;
    width: 600px;
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 2em;
    border-radius: 0.5ex;
}

#sticky.stick {
    margin-top: 0 !important;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10000;
    border-radius: 0 0 0.5em 0.5em;
}

body {
    margin: 1em;
}

p {
    margin: 1em auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse scelerisque, lectus in pharetra blandit, augue mauris pulvinar erat, ut euismod nibh lectus sed diam. Nulla fringilla ultrices ligula. Aliquam vitae felis metus. Maecenas lacinia bibendum
    accumsan. Curabitur lobortis convallis purus non imperdiet. Morbi ut vulputate mauris. Curabitur lacinia faucibus volutpat. Nulla elit tortor, rhoncus ut luctus eget, blandit in risus. Integer accumsan ullamcorper lorem id porttitor. Aliquam vitae
    libero eget magna mollis gravida.
</p>
<div id="sticky-anchor"></div>
<div id="sticky">This will stay at top of page</div>
<p>Nunc eu sapien turpis. Proin non arcu orci, eget volutpat tellus. Maecenas tempor mattis risus, quis pellentesque eros imperdiet nec. Vestibulum porttitor, justo at ornare bibendum, magna lectus cursus felis, tristique consectetur arcu justo at augue.
    Mauris ultrices mollis sem eget elementum. Sed ipsum orci, tempus vel porttitor vel, tristique eu erat. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Duis aliquam pulvinar nisl, vitae congue velit ultricies
    eget.
</p>


<p>Maecenas mollis arcu orci. Nam nec velit dolor, ut convallis augue. Morbi sed massa nunc. Vestibulum malesuada eros sed purus volutpat nec bibendum neque sodales. Nullam tincidunt quam sit amet lacus egestas vitae ultrices mauris porta. Duis vel neque
    ipsum. Vestibulum eu blandit ante. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec turpis leo, hendrerit quis elementum tincidunt, auctor ac augue. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis
    egestas.
</p>
<p>Sed in eleifend magna. Morbi faucibus eleifend nunc eu sagittis. Curabitur accumsan nulla in neque tempor eu lacinia elit consectetur. Nullam scelerisque ligula vitae nisi interdum pellentesque. Vivamus lobortis tempor pulvinar. Nunc sit amet nulla urna.
    Phasellus malesuada euismod lectus nec bibendum. Ut adipiscing dapibus ipsum nec iaculis. Donec quis dignissim tortor. Suspendisse molestie rhoncus enim hendrerit ultricies. Proin semper purus posuere urna porttitor suscipit.</p>
<p>Curabitur odio dui, imperdiet sed sodales nec, aliquet id nisl. Mauris nec sapien nibh. Maecenas vel sem at felis posuere rutrum non non mauris. Maecenas at lectus ut ipsum iaculis lobortis. Vivamus ut porta nisi. Phasellus tempor accumsan urna eu faucibus.
    Duis sed ligula neque, pulvinar euismod velit. Donec tristique eros at dolor ornare sagittis. Vestibulum sodales imperdiet ante et tincidunt. Suspendisse malesuada tempor nisi ac accumsan. Pellentesque accumsan pulvinar odio, id adipiscing diam mollis
    eu. Nulla id mi rutrum elit rutrum ultrices. Maecenas viverra, est ut pellentesque ultricies, ligula nisi auctor tellus, vitae bibendum mi nunc non libero. Mauris in facilisis enim. Proin facilisis, risus et tempus accumsan, orci enim egestas arcu,
    sit amet sodales risus leo quis nisi.</p>
<p>Nunc eu sapien turpis. Proin non arcu orci, eget volutpat tellus. Maecenas tempor mattis risus, quis pellentesque eros imperdiet nec. Vestibulum porttitor, justo at ornare bibendum, magna lectus cursus felis, tristique consectetur arcu justo at augue.
    Mauris ultrices mollis sem eget elementum. Sed ipsum orci, tempus vel porttitor vel, tristique eu erat. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Duis aliquam pulvinar nisl, vitae congue velit ultricies
    eget.
</p>
<div class="parar">

<p>
<B>PARAR AQUI</B>
</p>

</div>
<p>Maecenas mollis arcu orci. Nam nec velit dolor, ut convallis augue. Morbi sed massa nunc. Vestibulum malesuada eros sed purus volutpat nec bibendum neque sodales. Nullam tincidunt quam sit amet lacus egestas vitae ultrices mauris porta. Duis vel neque
    ipsum. Vestibulum eu blandit ante. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec turpis leo, hendrerit quis elementum tincidunt, auctor ac augue. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis
    egestas.
</p>
<p>Sed in eleifend magna. Morbi faucibus eleifend nunc eu sagittis. Curabitur accumsan nulla in neque tempor eu lacinia elit consectetur. Nullam scelerisque ligula vitae nisi interdum pellentesque. Vivamus lobortis tempor pulvinar. Nunc sit amet nulla urna.
    Phasellus malesuada euismod lectus nec bibendum. Ut adipiscing dapibus ipsum nec iaculis. Donec quis dignissim tortor. Suspendisse molestie rhoncus enim hendrerit ultricies. Proin semper purus posuere urna porttitor suscipit.</p>
<p>Curabitur odio dui, imperdiet sed sodales nec, aliquet id nisl. Mauris nec sapien nibh. Maecenas vel sem at felis posuere rutrum non non mauris. Maecenas at lectus ut ipsum iaculis lobortis. Vivamus ut porta nisi. Phasellus tempor accumsan urna eu faucibus.
    Duis sed ligula neque, pulvinar euismod velit. Donec tristique eros at dolor ornare sagittis. Vestibulum sodales imperdiet ante et tincidunt. Suspendisse malesuada tempor nisi ac accumsan. Pellentesque accumsan pulvinar odio, id adipiscing diam mollis
    eu. Nulla id mi rutrum elit rutrum ultrices. Maecenas viverra, est ut pellentesque ultricies, ligula nisi auctor tellus, vitae bibendum mi nunc non libero. Mauris in facilisis enim. Proin facilisis, risus et tempus accumsan, orci enim egestas arcu,
    sit amet sodales risus leo quis nisi.</p>
<p>Nunc eu sapien turpis. Proin non arcu orci, eget volutpat tellus. Maecenas tempor mattis risus, quis pellentesque eros imperdiet nec. Vestibulum porttitor, justo at ornare bibendum, magna lectus cursus felis, tristique consectetur arcu justo at augue.
    Mauris ultrices mollis sem eget elementum. Sed ipsum orci, tempus vel porttitor vel, tristique eu erat. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Duis aliquam pulvinar nisl, vitae congue velit ultricies
    eget.
</p>
<p>Maecenas mollis arcu orci. Nam nec velit dolor, ut convallis augue. Morbi sed massa nunc. Vestibulum malesuada eros sed purus volutpat nec bibendum neque sodales. Nullam tincidunt quam sit amet lacus egestas vitae ultrices mauris porta. Duis vel neque
    ipsum. Vestibulum eu blandit ante. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec turpis leo, hendrerit quis elementum tincidunt, auctor ac augue. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis
    egestas.
</p>
<p>Sed in eleifend magna. Morbi faucibus eleifend nunc eu sagittis. Curabitur accumsan nulla in neque tempor eu lacinia elit consectetur. Nullam scelerisque ligula vitae nisi interdum pellentesque. Vivamus lobortis tempor pulvinar. Nunc sit amet nulla urna.
    Phasellus malesuada euismod lectus nec bibendum. Ut adipiscing dapibus ipsum nec iaculis. Donec quis dignissim tortor. Suspendisse molestie rhoncus enim hendrerit ultricies. Proin semper purus posuere urna porttitor suscipit.</p>
<p>Curabitur odio dui, imperdiet sed sodales nec, aliquet id nisl. Mauris nec sapien nibh. Maecenas vel sem at felis posuere rutrum non non mauris. Maecenas at lectus ut ipsum iaculis lobortis. Vivamus ut porta nisi. Phasellus tempor accumsan urna eu faucibus.
    Duis sed ligula neque, pulvinar euismod velit. Donec tristique eros at dolor ornare sagittis. Vestibulum sodales imperdiet ante et tincidunt. Suspendisse malesuada tempor nisi ac accumsan. Pellentesque accumsan pulvinar odio, id adipiscing diam mollis
    eu. Nulla id mi rutrum elit rutrum ultrices. Maecenas viverra, est ut pellentesque ultricies, ligula nisi auctor tellus, vitae bibendum mi nunc non libero. Mauris in facilisis enim. Proin facilisis, risus et tempus accumsan, orci enim egestas arcu,
    sit amet sodales risus leo quis nisi.</p>
```

Comment: Não ficou claro. A div fica fixa ao passar pelo scroll... ao voltar o scroll ela volta pro lugar, deixando de ficar fixa... qual seria a dúvida?

Comment: repare que ali emabaixo tem PARAR AQUI, é ali que eu quero que volte pro lugar

Comment: Ah sim... seria bom colocar isso na pergunta para ficar mais clara.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode pegar a posição do `scroll` da janela e diminuir pela posição da `div #parar` em relação ao topo do documento. Quando o resultado for maior que `0`, retirar a `class` `.stick` da `div` fixa, que voltará para a posição natural:

```
var parar_top = window_top - $('.parar').offset().top;
```

Para isso, basta inserir uma segunda condição obrigatória (`&&`) no `if`:

```
if (window_top > div_top && parar_top < 0) {...
```

**Veja:**

```js
function sticky_relocate() {
    var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
    var div_top = $('#sticky-anchor').offset().top;

    var parar_top = window_top - $('.parar').offset().top;

    if (window_top > div_top && parar_top < 0) {
        $('#sticky').addClass('stick');
        $('#sticky-anchor').height($('#sticky').outerHeight());
    } else {
        $('#sticky').removeClass('stick');
        $('#sticky-anchor').height(0);
    }
}

$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(sticky_relocate);
    sticky_relocate();
});
```

```css
#sticky {
    padding: 0.5ex;
    width: 600px;
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 2em;
    border-radius: 0.5ex;
}

#sticky.stick {
    margin-top: 0 !important;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10000;
    border-radius: 0 0 0.5em 0.5em;
}

body {
    margin: 1em;
}

p {
    margin: 1em auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse scelerisque, lectus in pharetra blandit, augue mauris pulvinar erat, ut euismod nibh lectus sed diam. Nulla fringilla ultrices ligula. Aliquam vitae felis metus. Maecenas lacinia bibendum
    accumsan. Curabitur lobortis convallis purus non imperdiet. Morbi ut vulputate mauris. Curabitur lacinia faucibus volutpat. Nulla elit tortor, rhoncus ut luctus eget, blandit in risus. Integer accumsan ullamcorper lorem id porttitor. Aliquam vitae
    libero eget magna mollis gravida.
</p>
<div id="sticky-anchor"></div>
<div id="sticky">This will stay at top of page</div>
<p>Nunc eu sapien turpis. Proin non arcu orci, eget volutpat tellus. Maecenas tempor mattis risus, quis pellentesque eros imperdiet nec. Vestibulum porttitor, justo at ornare bibendum, magna lectus cursus felis, tristique consectetur arcu justo at augue.
    Mauris ultrices mollis sem eget elementum. Sed ipsum orci, tempus vel porttitor vel, tristique eu erat. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Duis aliquam pulvinar nisl, vitae congue velit ultricies
    eget.
</p>


<p>Maecenas mollis arcu orci. Nam nec velit dolor, ut convallis augue. Morbi sed massa nunc. Vestibulum malesuada eros sed purus volutpat nec bibendum neque sodales. Nullam tincidunt quam sit amet lacus egestas vitae ultrices mauris porta. Duis vel neque
    ipsum. Vestibulum eu blandit ante. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec turpis leo, hendrerit quis elementum tincidunt, auctor ac augue. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis
    egestas.
</p>
<p>Sed in eleifend magna. Morbi faucibus eleifend nunc eu sagittis. Curabitur accumsan nulla in neque tempor eu lacinia elit consectetur. Nullam scelerisque ligula vitae nisi interdum pellentesque. Vivamus lobortis tempor pulvinar. Nunc sit amet nulla urna.
    Phasellus malesuada euismod lectus nec bibendum. Ut adipiscing dapibus ipsum nec iaculis. Donec quis dignissim tortor. Suspendisse molestie rhoncus enim hendrerit ultricies. Proin semper purus posuere urna porttitor suscipit.</p>
<p>Curabitur odio dui, imperdiet sed sodales nec, aliquet id nisl. Mauris nec sapien nibh. Maecenas vel sem at felis posuere rutrum non non mauris. Maecenas at lectus ut ipsum iaculis lobortis. Vivamus ut porta nisi. Phasellus tempor accumsan urna eu faucibus.
    Duis sed ligula neque, pulvinar euismod velit. Donec tristique eros at dolor ornare sagittis. Vestibulum sodales imperdiet ante et tincidunt. Suspendisse malesuada tempor nisi ac accumsan. Pellentesque accumsan pulvinar odio, id adipiscing diam mollis
    eu. Nulla id mi rutrum elit rutrum ultrices. Maecenas viverra, est ut pellentesque ultricies, ligula nisi auctor tellus, vitae bibendum mi nunc non libero. Mauris in facilisis enim. Proin facilisis, risus et tempus accumsan, orci enim egestas arcu,
    sit amet sodales risus leo quis nisi.</p>
<p>Nunc eu sapien turpis. Proin non arcu orci, eget volutpat tellus. Maecenas tempor mattis risus, quis pellentesque eros imperdiet nec. Vestibulum porttitor, justo at ornare bibendum, magna lectus cursus felis, tristique consectetur arcu justo at augue.
    Mauris ultrices mollis sem eget elementum. Sed ipsum orci, tempus vel porttitor vel, tristique eu erat. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Duis aliquam pulvinar nisl, vitae congue velit ultricies
    eget.
</p>
<div class="parar">

<p>
<B>PARAR AQUI</B>
</p>

</div>
<p>Maecenas mollis arcu orci. Nam nec velit dolor, ut convallis augue. Morbi sed massa nunc. Vestibulum malesuada eros sed purus volutpat nec bibendum neque sodales. Nullam tincidunt quam sit amet lacus egestas vitae ultrices mauris porta. Duis vel neque
    ipsum. Vestibulum eu blandit ante. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec turpis leo, hendrerit quis elementum tincidunt, auctor ac augue. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis
    egestas.
</p>
<p>Sed in eleifend magna. Morbi faucibus eleifend nunc eu sagittis. Curabitur accumsan nulla in neque tempor eu lacinia elit consectetur. Nullam scelerisque ligula vitae nisi interdum pellentesque. Vivamus lobortis tempor pulvinar. Nunc sit amet nulla urna.
    Phasellus malesuada euismod lectus nec bibendum. Ut adipiscing dapibus ipsum nec iaculis. Donec quis dignissim tortor. Suspendisse molestie rhoncus enim hendrerit ultricies. Proin semper purus posuere urna porttitor suscipit.</p>
<p>Curabitur odio dui, imperdiet sed sodales nec, aliquet id nisl. Mauris nec sapien nibh. Maecenas vel sem at felis posuere rutrum non non mauris. Maecenas at lectus ut ipsum iaculis lobortis. Vivamus ut porta nisi. Phasellus tempor accumsan urna eu faucibus.
    Duis sed ligula neque, pulvinar euismod velit. Donec tristique eros at dolor ornare sagittis. Vestibulum sodales imperdiet ante et tincidunt. Suspendisse malesuada tempor nisi ac accumsan. Pellentesque accumsan pulvinar odio, id adipiscing diam mollis
    eu. Nulla id mi rutrum elit rutrum ultrices. Maecenas viverra, est ut pellentesque ultricies, ligula nisi auctor tellus, vitae bibendum mi nunc non libero. Mauris in facilisis enim. Proin facilisis, risus et tempus accumsan, orci enim egestas arcu,
    sit amet sodales risus leo quis nisi.</p>
<p>Nunc eu sapien turpis. Proin non arcu orci, eget volutpat tellus. Maecenas tempor mattis risus, quis pellentesque eros imperdiet nec. Vestibulum porttitor, justo at ornare bibendum, magna lectus cursus felis, tristique consectetur arcu justo at augue.
    Mauris ultrices mollis sem eget elementum. Sed ipsum orci, tempus vel porttitor vel, tristique eu erat. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Duis aliquam pulvinar nisl, vitae congue velit ultricies
    eget.
</p>
<p>Maecenas mollis arcu orci. Nam nec velit dolor, ut convallis augue. Morbi sed massa nunc. Vestibulum malesuada eros sed purus volutpat nec bibendum neque sodales. Nullam tincidunt quam sit amet lacus egestas vitae ultrices mauris porta. Duis vel neque
    ipsum. Vestibulum eu blandit ante. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec turpis leo, hendrerit quis elementum tincidunt, auctor ac augue. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis
    egestas.
</p>
<p>Sed in eleifend magna. Morbi faucibus eleifend nunc eu sagittis. Curabitur accumsan nulla in neque tempor eu lacinia elit consectetur. Nullam scelerisque ligula vitae nisi interdum pellentesque. Vivamus lobortis tempor pulvinar. Nunc sit amet nulla urna.
    Phasellus malesuada euismod lectus nec bibendum. Ut adipiscing dapibus ipsum nec iaculis. Donec quis dignissim tortor. Suspendisse molestie rhoncus enim hendrerit ultricies. Proin semper purus posuere urna porttitor suscipit.</p>
<p>Curabitur odio dui, imperdiet sed sodales nec, aliquet id nisl. Mauris nec sapien nibh. Maecenas vel sem at felis posuere rutrum non non mauris. Maecenas at lectus ut ipsum iaculis lobortis. Vivamus ut porta nisi. Phasellus tempor accumsan urna eu faucibus.
    Duis sed ligula neque, pulvinar euismod velit. Donec tristique eros at dolor ornare sagittis. Vestibulum sodales imperdiet ante et tincidunt. Suspendisse malesuada tempor nisi ac accumsan. Pellentesque accumsan pulvinar odio, id adipiscing diam mollis
    eu. Nulla id mi rutrum elit rutrum ultrices. Maecenas viverra, est ut pellentesque ultricies, ligula nisi auctor tellus, vitae bibendum mi nunc non libero. Mauris in facilisis enim. Proin facilisis, risus et tempus accumsan, orci enim egestas arcu,
    sit amet sodales risus leo quis nisi.</p>
```